# Spring Cloud Sleuth + log4j2

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-sleuth

Some of my microservices use log4j2 as logger. Spring cloud Sleuth has support for logback. How can I use Sleuth to get distributed tracing in this scenario. I understand to use sleuth with log4j2, I have to implement certain class. I tried this but no luck. 
Please help

Comment: Any help here, stuck with same issue. Only possible solution seems is to integrate brave library directly

Answer (score 4):

`Sleuth` puts the traceId and spanId in the `MDC`(Mapped Diagnostic Context).

You can use `%X` to check the MDC key value pairs, and Sleuth related keys are `traceId`, `spanId`, `parentId`, `spanExportable`.

To simulate the logback default style, just maunally add below snippet into your `PatternLayout`:

```
[${APP_NAME},%X{traceId},%X{spanId},%X{spanExportable}]
```

`${APP_NAME}` is just your `spring:application:name`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the latest 2.0.0.M6 release where we use Brave internally. You can check out the https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/tree/master/context/log4j12 module how to set up the logging mechanism properly.

In Spring Cloud Sleuth just create a bean like this:

```
@Bean
CurrentTraceContext log4jTraceContext() {
return MDCCurrentTraceContext.create();
}
```

Comment: I think he asked about Log4j2, not Log4j12

Comment: I just tried with log4j2. It should work out of the box as soon as you disable slf4j i.e set `spring.sleuth.log.slf4j.enabled=false`

Comment: `spring.sleuth.log.slf4j.enabled=false` doesn't work for me.

Comment: The correct dependency is `io.zipkin.brave:brave-context-log4j2` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57987624/).

Answer (score 0):

This is my example log4j2 configuration that logs in JSON including Sleuth's `spanId` and `traceId`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleJson" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <JsonLayout complete="false" compact="true" eventEol="true" properties="true"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleJson"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

According to the log4j2 [Layouts documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout):

> properties
>
> boolean
>
> If true, the appender includes the thread context
>   map in the generated JSON. Defaults to false.

So the thread context map is an actual holder of this information, to use it in other layouts (`PatternLayout`) you must use some context map access keys like `%X{spanId}`.