# Spring-Cloud-Sleuth enable MDC properties in pattern layout to log TraceId

Tags: java, log4j2, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am not seeing the TraceId or SpanId in our log files after adding the spring-cloud-sleuth dependency.  We use log4j2 and slf4j.  Apparently this works out of the box with logback but not log4j2.  It seems other people have had success using the json layout by adding properties=true in the config file but we use pattern layout and it doesn't seem that boolean is available.  I have configured the pattern correctly but that doesn't matter as when I set the debugger in the MDCPatternConverter class, the thread context map is empty.  I can make code changes and directly set MDC values but people downstream from us want us to use this dependency for some reason.

Added log4j-JUL
Added spring-boot-starter-log4j2

```
<Property name="STP_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS zzz} %-5p  [%X{X-B3-TraceId} TEST %X{X-B3-SpanId} %t:%c{1}:%x] -%m%n
    </Property>
```

Comment: Does your application use threads?  And are you logging messages within the new threads?  Or is all logging done within the main thread?

Comment: yes, it uses threads.  from the main entry point we have an @async method and it is only what happens in this method that we want to modify the logging as all the logging inside has its own appender

Answer (score 3):

Sleuth uses Brave under the hook. You have to add the `io.zipkin.brave:brave-context-log4j2` dependency to your classpath. Please check out Brave's documentation for more information https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/tree/master/context/log4j2 I'll copy it here for your convenience

> This adds trace and span IDs to the Log4J 2 Thread Context so that you
>   can search or aggregate logs accordingly.
>
> To enable this, configure brave.Tracing with
>   ThreadContextScopeDecorator like so:

Just create a bean of `ThreadContextScopeDecorator` type and Sleuth will pick it up

```
@Bean
ScopeDecorator threadContextScopeDecorator() {
return new ThreadContextScopeDecorator();
}
```

Comment: OK I have done this and still blank.  We are using spring cloud dependencies version Edgware.RELEASE and I am pulling in brave-context-log4j2 version 5.7.0.  We are unable to bump up the spring cloud version.  I have created the bean.  Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Edgware is an extremely old release train. Please upgrade to the latest version

Comment: Unfortunately we can't do that anytime soon.  Is it possible to get this to work using Edgware?

Comment: Nope. Brave is used starting from Finchley

Comment: You also need to override the property `logging.pattern.level` e.g. with `%5p [${spring.zipkin.service.name:${spring.application.name:}},%X{traceId},%X{spanId}]`. There seems to be a bug in `TraceEnvironmentPostProcessor`. The syntax `%X{traceId:-}` with empty default value doesn't work with log4j2 afaik. See [Pattern Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout).

Comment: See bug report [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2008)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log within spawned threads you need to copy the MDC thread local context from the current thread into the new one.

In the main thread...

```
 final Map<String, String> threadContext = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
 Runnable mythread = () -> { MDC.setContextMap(threadContext); 
                             yourCode(); };
 new Thread(mythread).start();
```

Comment: I tried starting the app using -DisThreadContextMapInheritable=true and that didn't work, isn't that the equivalent of your code?

Comment: From https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html

... based on ThreadLocal by default. The Map can be configured to use an InheritableThreadLocal by setting system property log4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable to true. When configured this way, the contents of the Map will be passed to child threads. However, as discussed in the Executors class and in other cases where thread pooling is utilized, the ThreadContext may not always be automatically passed to worker threads. In those cases the pooling mechanism should provide a means for doing so.

Comment: Wanted to follow up with this that I did a test.  I removed the @async from the method I am interested in tracing the logs and still no dice.  So its not a thread pool issue apparently but related to what dependencies I am bringing in.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is the following:

- add io.zipkin.brave:brave-context-log4j2 dependency
- Add org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2 dependency
- Add org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth dependency
- Exclude default spring logging

  ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
  ```
- in your log4j2.xml adjust the pattern layout

  ```
  <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%X{traceId}, %X{spanId}] {%-5level} - %l - %m%n" />
  ```